# How to evaluate a $1$-form on a vector field?

Tags: differential-forms

I have the one form : $dz + x\, dy$.

If I want to evaluate this on a vector field, say $-\partial_{z}$, how do I do it?

I don't understand what 1-forms defined with an exterior derivative do to vector fields. An answer for general one-form and/or a resolution for the mentioned case would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "compute this in a vector"? Do you mean you want to evaluate the one-form $dz + xdy$ on the vector field $-\partial_z$?

Comment: Yes ! this is what I meant. I will edit that.

Comment: I reworded (and retitled) the question guided by your comment. If I changed your intended meaning, please roll back the edit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}\newcommand{\Basis}{\mathbf{e}}\newcommand{\dd}{\partial}$First, $(dz + x\, dy)(-\dd_{z}) = -1$.

Generally, working in $\Reals^{3}$ for concreteness, if $(x, y, z)$ denotes some coordinate system, $(\dd_{x}, \dd_{y}, \dd_{z})$ denotes the associated coordinate vector fields, and $(dx, dy, dz)$ denotes the coordinate $1$-forms, then
$$
dx(\dd_{x}) = \frac{\dd x}{\dd x} = 1,\qquad
dy(\dd_{y}) = \frac{\dd y}{\dd y} = 1,\qquad
dz(\dd_{z}) = \frac{\dd z}{\dd z} = 1,
$$
and all other evaluations are zero.

To handle general forms and/or vector fields, "extend using bilinearity over smooth functions". Concretely, if $\omega = f_{1}\, dx + f_{2}\, dy + f_{3}\, dz$ is a general $1$-form, then
$$
\omega(\dd_{x}) = f_{1},\qquad
\omega(\dd_{y}) = f_{2},\qquad
\omega(\dd_{z}) = f_{3}.
$$
If $v = v_{1}\, \dd_{x} + v_{2}\, \dd_{y} + v_{3}\, \dd_{z}$ is a general vector field, then
$$
\omega(v) = f_{1} v_{1} + f_{2} v_{2} + f_{3} v_{3}.
$$

Comment: Hi, sorry for necropost. This seems confusing in that I thought this evaluation would output a scalar on the base field. In, e.g., contact forms, we seek the kernel of a 1-form. Using the one in this problem:$dz+xdy$, then: set $(dz+xdy)[)(\frac {{f_1 \dd}{ x} +\frac { f_2 \dd}{ y} +f_3 \ddl z)] =f_3 +x f_2x_ $ , is not a scalar. Do I then evaluate at points (x,y,z) to get a scalar? Thanks

Comment: @MSIS Any $1$-form $\omega$ on a manifold $M$ is an element of the cotangent bundle $T^*M$. It acts (fiberwise) on elements of the tangent bundle $TM$ by sending them to scalars in the base field. A vector field $X:M\to TM$ on $M$ is a family of vectors $X_p$ which vary as $p$ varies. The evaluation of $\omega$ on a *vector field* should somehow remember this "changing in $p$" business. It therefore makes sense to think of $\omega(X)$ as a *function on $M$*, and its defined $\omega(X)(p) = \omega(X_p)$. This is a scalar-valued *function* on $M$.